# Go back to tab bar controller with index 2

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[this is my procedural scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6A2j.png)
i have a tab controllore with 3 items and into 1 items i have a navigation controller than into this i have a popup

i need to go back from my popup to my tab bar controller with index 2

this is my code but doesn't work.

```
let TabViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController
    self.present(TabViewController, animated: true)
```

I have to be able to go back from my popup, to my tab bar controller directly to the page with item 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
self.dismiss(animated:true) {
     let TabViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController
     TabViewController.selectedIndex = 2
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = TabViewController 
}
```

Comment: I just tried but I get this error: "Value of type 'UITabBarController' has no member 'selecetdIndex'"

Comment: nothing happens, it stays in the view controller where I call the function.
but without error.
I need to declaration something into che tabbarview controller?

Comment: Is the root in storyboard the tap ?

Comment: the procedure is:
loginviewcontroller -> tabViewController -> item1 item2 item3. into item 2 I have a navigation controller with a table view and at the selected row a new pag call DetailViewController and into this I have a popUp where I do something and into this when I touchup inside my button called "confermaButton" I need to retune into item 2

Comment: I add into my ask the photo with scheme if you want you can see that